# RightBarButtonItem Upper Case Text?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, uinavigationbar

I have a simple Edit Button on my NavigationBar once clicked turns to Done, I'm trying to change the text on both 'Edit' and 'Done' to uppercase text, is this possible? Does anybody know of a tutorial I can check out?

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should note that the Edit and Done buttons are automatically localised to the user's chosen language, and replacing them would remove this feature.  Plus uppercase text just looks plain bad.... DO YOU LIKE IT WHEN PEOPLE SHOUT ALL THE TIME??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create btnEdit object of `UIBarButtonItem` in .h file like bellow:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnEdit;
```

and then in `.m` file write this code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    btnEdit = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
    btnEdit.target = self;
    btnEdit.action = @selector(btnEdit_Click:);
    btnEdit.title = @"EDIT";
    self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnEdit;
    btnEdit.enabled=TRUE;
 }

- (IBAction)btnEdit_Click:(id)sender
{
    if ([btnEdit.title isEqualToString:@"EDIT"]) 
    {
        [btnEdit setTitle:@"DONE"]; 
    }
    else 
    {
        [btnEdit setTitle:@"EDIT"];   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *newButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"EDIT" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: @selector(editPressed:self)];

[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem: newButton animated:NO];

newBackButton = nil;
```

and then:

```
- (void)editPressed:(id)sender
{
     // Your code
}
```